# how to do a fast regex search on a hdf5 database

Tags: regex, database, hdf5

I have an HDF5 database with 100 million+ rows of text each storing a simple three column set of values:

```
ID WORD HEADWORD
1 the the
2 cats cat
3 sat sit
4 on on
5 the the
6 mats mat
...
```

I want to do a search on the "WORD" column to find all hits for *at* (i.e., 'cats', 'sat', 'mats').

In some other database (e.g. PostgresQL) I might do this with a simple regex search '?at?'. If I could search the HDF5 index using regex, that would be fine. But, I don't think this is possible. Any suggestions for how to do this kind of 'wildcard' (regex) search quickly?

Comment: Try `^[ \t]*\d+[ \t]+\w*at\w*` or `^[ \t]*[0-9]+[ \t]+[a-zA-Z]*at[a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: The suggestions given already are focusing on the regex part. I know how to write regex. What I don't know is how to do a regex search **on a HDF5 database via the index**. I don't want to have to select every row and do a regex match on each one. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no "index" in an HDF5 file (assuming you're using "index" in a database sense). HDF5 files are definitely not databases in the way PostgreSQL is a database. HDF5 files are, essentially, big binary blobs of data.There are lots of advantages of HDF5 files, but not for the usage case described here. So to answer your question, there is no way to do a regexp search especially quickly, just as there would be no way to do a search especially quickly on a text file with the same data.

Comment: Thanks for this Justin. The columnar structure (and the portability) is what I like. HDF5 files can have a (database) index attached, though. I've also heard of talk of making the indexes regex searchable. But, not yet it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Try following regex

```
[^\s]+[\s]+([a-zA-Z]*at[a-zA-Z]*)[\s]+[^\s]+
```

Group 1 in above regex will give you desired result.

```
"WORD" column to find all hits for at (i.e., 'cats', 'sat', 'mats').
```

- [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/x9yfQc5DUsIgXURb)
- [Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uwsjmb/1)